# Central limit theorem heuristics

Tags: distributions, sampling, random-variable, central-limit-theorem

I have found the following statement on the internet concerning the necessary number of samples in the central limit theorem:

> In practice, some statisticians say that a sample size of 30 is large
>   enough when the population distribution is roughly bell-shaped. Others
>   recommend a sample size of at least 40. But if the original population
>   is distinctly not normal (e.g., is badly skewed, has multiple peaks,
>   and/or has outliers), researchers like the sample size to be even
>   larger. [1]

I need some references that prove this claim (i.e. scientific papers that actually recomend this sample size of 30 or 40). ¿Do you known any of them?

[1] http://stattrek.com/sampling/sampling-distribution.aspx

Comment: 1. "recommend" $\neq$ "prove".  Which is it?

Comment: this was answered here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2541/is-there-a-reference-that-suggest-using-30-as-a-large-enough-sample-size

Comment: The claim is so vague as to be meaningless. It doesn't specify what would constitute some sufficient approximation to normality, so it's impossible to evaluate whether it's really achieved in some instance.

Comment: The author of the cite claims that statisticians recommend sample sizes of 30, I asked for a prove of this claim, i.e. a reference where a statistician recommends a sample size of 30.

Comment: (on the off chance this reopens) ... How is "statistician" defined? How could someone support a claim like this unless it was precise about what was actually being claimed?