# How many sample do we need for normality of t-ratio?

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval, t-distribution

I am currently learning about confidence intervals for the population mean.
Assume we do not know the variance of the population.
Let $\bar{x}$ be the sample mean, $s$ be the sample variance and $n$ the sample size.
I learnt the following:

- Use $\bar{x}\pm t_{\alpha,n-1}\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$ if the data is normally distributed, where $t_{\alpha,n-1}$ is the $\alpha$ t-score from the $T$ distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom.
- If the data is not normally distributed, then with a large enough sample we can use the z-interval $\bar{x}\pm z_{\alpha}\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$ where $z_{\alpha}$ is a suitable z-score.
  The reason is that the T-ratio $T=\bar{x}-\mu/(s/\sqrt{n})$ becomes approximately normal with a large enough sample.

The lecture notes mention that we can consider $n=30$ a large enough sample size but without providing any explanation. So my question is simple: *Why $n=30$*?

Comment: It is generally [*not* true](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2541/what-references-should-be-cited-to-support-using-30-as-a-large-enough-sample-siz) that $n=30$ is sufficient.

Comment: If $\alpha=0.05$ you get $z_\alpha=1.96$ in your two-tailed example, which people sometimes round to $2$.  The equivalent $t_{\alpha,30}\approx 2.04$ which also rounds to $2$

Comment: See [this site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=test+n+30) for many posts about this subject.